# Why InstanceID always returns a token despite of wrong senderId?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, instanceid

I'm using Google Cloud Messaging api to implement an Android client. To get a token, I do:

```
   InstanceID ex = InstanceID.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
   String regId = ex.getToken(senderId, "GCM", null);
```

And regId always contains a token, despite of I put on senderId. If I set senderId with "123", InstanceID returns a token! (But the, I don't receive notifications with this token). Why I always get a token? I expect an exception, or a null value maybe...

Answer (score 0):

You may always get a token but you will not be able to use it to establish the full gcm lifecycle since `instanceId` is tied to your app server's `senderId`.

From the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/)

> Use the `getToken` method to prove the ownership of the InstanceID and
>   to allow servers to access data or services associated with the app.
>   The method follows the patterns of OAuth2, and requires an
>   authorizedEntity and scope. The authorizedEntity can be a project ID
>   or another InstanceID, and it determines the services that are
>   authorized to use the generated token. The scope determines the
>   specific service or data to which the token allows access.

To understand more of the lifecycle, refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/#instance_id_lifecycle)